# using a div as a radio button

Tags: php, jquery, html, radio-button

```
<div>
    <table class='accor'>
        <tr>
            <td>Roll No.</td>
            <td>12801</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>XXXX</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Class</td>
            <td>MS</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

i want the above code as a radio button. the above code is running inside a php while loop with the data supplied from a database. (i also need to use `checked=checked` to match a predefined value.)
i am using the [jquery ui buttonset style](http://jqueryui.com/button/#radio) with the radio.

how can i achieve that?

Comment: what have u tried till now ?

Comment: show us what you have done so far..

Comment: i've tried the jquery `(selector).click()` and then submitting the form through ajax ($.post) to update the selections in a xml file. which works fine without even using a radio button. but i'm unable to use the ui buttonset and checked=checked options with my approach. sorry i can't show you the code as most of them are php ones with `echo` and variables. and can't show that in fiddle.

Comment: So, you want the entire `div` to be displayed like a single radio button choice?

Comment: @CheeseWarlock yep. exactly. for each `div` i want to have a value and for a group of `div`s i want use a common name just like the radio buttons.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not sure I understand. You can put elements inside the `label` for the `input`, if this sort of thing is what you're after: http://jsfiddle.net/q3RNe/

Comment: @CheeseWarlock
thanks man. i never used label with inputs yet. i was just using table. in one td, the label of the input (just the text), in another the element. thanks again. pls write it as a answer so that i can accept and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$().buttonset` takes all the `input type='radio'` elements inside the selector and makes a stylized button set out of them. For each of these elements, the associated `label` is placed on the display of the resulting button. So to have buttons with labels that aren't just a single line of text, just place the contents inside the `label`.

```
<form>
  <div id="radio">
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" />
      <label for="radio1">
        <div>
          <table class='accor'>
            <tr>
              <td>Roll No.</td>
              <td>12801</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>XXXX</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </label>
      <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" checked="checked" />
      <label for="radio2"><div>
        <table class='accor'>
          <tr>
            <td>Roll No.</td>
            <td>12801</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>XXXX</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("#radio").buttonset();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try following (embed your code as you want):

```
$('.accor td').on("click",function(){
   $('td').css('background-color','#eee');
    var rowNumber = $(this).closest('tr').index();    
    setSelected(rowNumber);  
});

function setSelected(rowNumber){    
    $('tr').eq(rowNumber).find('td').css('background-color','#ccc');   
}

setSelected(2);
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZEwpE/2/

i hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

or another option to do that is:

```
$('.accor td').on("click",function(){
  $('td').css('background-color','#eee');
  var tr = $(this).parent();
  $(tr).children().css('background-color','#ccc');    
});
```

1. Get click event
2. Get parent (in your case it's )
3. Set css style to all childs of our

But it's only alternate (very similar) method:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/natanielcz/ZEwpE/3/)